# Does Ruby have a constant for cross-platform EOL somewhere?

Tags: ruby

I need to format a String that ends with a newline. I'd just add a "\n", but I want this to work on Windows too. Many languages have a constant that provides the appropriate CR/LF/CRLF sequence according to the platform, but I can't seem to find anything in Ruby. Does it exist?

Comment: You could add "\r\n", which always works, AFAIK. You can also specify the record separator for calls to print and write through the variable $\

Comment: Are you just outputting the string via something like puts?  Since puts will use the correct EOL for $PLATFORM, or do you need interior line breaks as well?

Comment: Writing \r\n to files in UNIX systems makes a horrible mess.

Comment: It's for a log formatter, so the data may be going into files, or to STDOUT, yep :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ruby's got four (!)

```
p $/
p $-0
require 'English'
p $RS
p $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR
```

Using IO#puts (= File#puts) will take care of the proper EOL, no need to set it manually.

Comment: These are all *input* record separators, not cross platform EOL chars. On Windows they're set to `"\n"` too.